# Access Denied Exception Boolean StartWithCreateProcess(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)

Tags: c#, iis

I have hosted asp.net web application on IIS version 8.5 That web application execute the python(pythonfile.py) file with 2 parameter

1) parameter(python exe location):C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe

2) parameter(txt file):D:\MyFolder\mytxtfile.txt

I hosted my application on default website(Default Website->MyWebApplication)

when i run the MyWebApplication it give me  exception Access Denied 
(on my local machine application runs fine)

Comment: does the apppool user on the web box have full admin rights to go into the administrator user folders? (id hope not)

Comment: iis run on seperate user with different security policies than your standard account,  you might need to find the IIS user and assign read and execute permissions in in the folders and programs you are trying to launch.